# Function set(), delete duplicate letters instead of duplicate words

Tags: python

When I have:

```
overflow = set("overflow") # output: {"o", "v", "e", "r", "f", "l", "w"}
```

However, if I have:

```
variable = set("car", "train", "bike", "boat", "airplaine")
```

I want to delete duplicate letters instead of duplicate words.

How can I do this?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you want to keep the “words”? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried some loops, but without success.

Comment: does the order matter ??

Answer (score 1):

My take on problem:

```
from itertools import chain

variable = set(chain.from_iterable(["car", "train", "bike", "boat", "airplaine"]))
print(variable)
```

Output:

```
{'o', 'a', 'l', 'c', 'i', 't', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'p', 'n', 'k'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the set together into a single string with no delimiter and then create another set out of the individual letters:

```
>>> variable = set(["car", "train", "bike", "boat", "airplaine"])
>>> set("".join(variable))
{'r', 'b', 'o', 'i', 'a', 'k', 'p', 'n', 't', 'c', 'e', 'l'}
```

It's worth noting the creation of your set is incorrect.